# How do I add HTML to the "billing_email" field at WooCommerce checkout?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I would like to add a line of text below the `billing_email` field input box. The details are as follows.

Original HTML output.

```
<p class="form-row form-row-wide validate-required validate-email" id="billing_email_field" data-priority="110">
    <label for="billing_email" class="">Email address&nbsp;<abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr></label>
    <span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper">
        <input type="email" class="input-text " name="billing_email" id="billing_email" placeholder="" value="" autocomplete="email username">
    </span>
</p>
```

Modified HTML output.

```
<p class="form-row form-row-wide validate-required validate-email" id="billing_email_field" data-priority="110">
    <label for="billing_email" class="">Email address&nbsp;<abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr></label>
    <span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper">
        <input type="email" class="input-text " name="billing_email" id="billing_email" placeholder="" value="" autocomplete="email username">
    </span>
    <br>
    <span>Please enter the correct email address so that you can receive our emails.</span>
</p>
```

I tried to check the [WooCommerce help documentation - Customizing checkout fields using actions and filters](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/), but it was too difficult for me, so I am asking for help here.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make a change specifically and only for the `billing_email` field, you can use the `'woocommerce_form_field_' . $args['type'],` filter hook. Where `$args['type']` can be replaced with type `email`

`$field` contains all HTML from `<p>` to the closing `</p>`. However, because you want to add new HTML between the existing code, instead of rewriting the entire field, you can use [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

So you get:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_form_field_email( $field, $key, $args, $value ) {   
    // Billing email
    if ( $key === 'billing_email') {
        // Replace existing html with new ones
        $field = str_replace( '</span>', '</span><br><span>Please enter the correct email address so that you can receive our emails.</span>', $field );
    }
    
    return $field;
} 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_form_field_email', 'filter_woocommerce_form_field_email', 10, 4 );
```

---

Related:

- [How should I change the woocommerce_form_field HTML Structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63999062/11987538)
- [WooCommerce: Change HTML structure of billing fields in checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61319684/11987538)
- [How to add HTML5 'required' attribute to woocommerce_form_field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64189633/11987538)